# Spring Integration - Read file by name

Tags: java, spring, integration, spring-boot, spring-integration

I want to read a file by name using Spring Integration. I know how to use file-adapter with poller. But in this case I just want to read a file by name and add it to the input channel.

My application is a standalone jar, and will be invoked using command-line arguments. One of the argument will be the file-name. I am using Spring-Boot as well. Just don't know how to initiate the processing by reading this file and adding this to an input-channel. Do I need a custom gateway?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to use `<context:property-placeholder>` and config like this:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter
        channel="input"
        directory="${dir}"
        filename-pattern="${pattern}">
    <poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" time-unit="SECONDS"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Where all those placeholders should be your program args, like this:

```
java myMain --dir=/usr/mydir --patter=myfile.name --fixedDelay=1000
```

**UPDATE**

However, no: you don't need `<context:property-placeholder>` - Spring Boot does that for you!

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry, you requirement is still not clear. Anyway how about this:

```
<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter channel="processFileChannel"
    event-types="org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent"
    payload-expression="new java.io.File('${filePath}')"/>
```

Where `filePath` is again an command line argument. And property placeholder from Spring Boot.

The `<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter>` is responsible to listen to `ApplicationEvent`. In this case we react to the `ContextRefreshedEvent` - a main event when you applicationContext is ready to do something.

Comment: Actually no. I just want to invoke a particular file by name. Each time it will be different. There is no pattern. And like I mentioned in the question, I don't need a poller as I there will nto be any polling with this being a standalone jar and not running on a web server.

Comment: Updated my answer with another solution.

Comment: That's interesting.. will try and let you know, thanks